# From where does sharepoint 2013 populate the "People and groups --> User Information"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have a team site inside sharepoint 2013. and on the user name drop down list, there is an item named "My setting". and clicing on this item menu , will redirect to a User info page contaning these data:-

```
Account
    SHAREPOINT\system
Name
    System Account
Work email

Mobile phone

About me


Picture

Department

Title

SIP Address

First name

Last name

Work phone

User name

Web site

Ask Me About


Office

Picture Timestamp


Picture Placeholder State

Picture Exchange Sync State
```

So my question is from where did SharePoint populate these data,, is it from the active directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the profile info comes from AD initially. If you have User Profile Service configured, you can see how the properties are mapped, also select other data sources (via BCS) to sync user profile data. With UPS, I think AD only syncs the name and email address.

Comment: And the information once fetched from AD is saved into a Hidden List called User Information List.. [Hidden User Information List](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list)

Comment: but if the AD is updated , will it be reflected on the user info list inside SharePoint ?

Comment: using User Profile Service, it'll sync at a defined time, otherwise the OOTB method is a one time sync up

Comment: Keep in mind that it doesn't necessarily come from AD - if you're using a membership database, for example, it comes from there... all depends on how your authentication provider is set up. For an OOTB site, though, your answer is dead on.